# Split a string at a single space

Tags: java, regex, string, split, character

I am looking to split a string into an array of strings at every single space.

For example:

`This_sentence_gets__split.` (Underscores represent spaces here)

Becomes

`"This"`

`"sentence"`

`"gets"`

`" "` (note the double space was left as one space)

`"split."`

I assume I can do this with `String.split(String regex)` but I am not very good with regular expressions and I do not know how I would accomplish this.

Edit:

Any spaces after the first should be split into substrings as well. For example:
`Split___this.` becomes `"Split` `" "` `" "` `"this."`

Comment: Your required output is not what you will get on splitting on single space. That `single space` will not be a different element in the array. So, basically, your double space will result in an empty string, and not a single space in the array.

Comment: @Fishstick How would you like to split data like: `A_B__C___D____E`?

Comment: @Pshemo Any additional spaces after the first would be split. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for (you can improve it with `\\s` class for all whitespace like tabs, new lines and so on)

```
String data = "This_sentence__gets___split".replace('_', ' ');
// System.out.println(data);
String arr[] = data.split("(?<! ) |(?<= {2})");
for (String s : arr)
    System.out.println("\"" + s + "\"");
```

Output:

```
"This"
"sentence"
" "
"gets"
" "
" "
"split."
```

Explanation:

- `"(?<! ) "` will split only on spaces that don't have space before it
- `"(?<= {2})"` will split in place that have two spaces before it.

Comment: +1 Nice work. I was about to edit my answer with the same, but didn't get the second regex in time :)

Comment: Thanks, accepted answer. While removing extra spaces would have been fine its good to learn this stuff. I will include it.

Comment: @Fishstick Glad you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `StringTokenizer`.

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test", " ", true);
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

The third parameter (**true**) will treat the delimiters as separate tokens, so that they will be returned separately.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that difficult:

```
str.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super knowledgeable on regular expressions either, which is why I choose to use [Google Guava's Splitter class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

Example:

```
private static final Splitter splitter = 
      Splitter.on(',').trimResults().omitEmptyStrings();

//results in {"some", "string"}
splitter.split("some string");
```

You can play around with trimResults(), omitEmptyStrings(), and other options to tweak it how you like.

:)